# Using gitpython to checkout-index

Tags: gitpython

I'm trying to determine how to perform a git-checkout-index via gitpython, and having difficulties.

I have shallow cloned the repo to a directory using `git.Repo.clone_from`.  I now wish to export this repo and specified branch to a directory.

The git cli syntax appears to be fairly straight forward.  From within the checked out repo issue `git checkout-index -f -a --prefix=/some/path/`.

Any idea how to translate this to `git.IndexFile`?  I also don't know how to translate the git cli syntax above direct to `git.IndexFile`.  It appears additional args can be passed to [checkout-index](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/caa0ea7a0893fe90ea043843d4e6ad407126d7b8/git/index/base.py#L993-L994).

```
g = git.IndexFile('/path/to/repo')
g.checkout(paths=None, force=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was able to figure this out.  Posting for others.

```
repo = git.Repo('/path/to/repo')
g = git.IndexFile(repo)
g.checkout(paths=None, force=False, prefix='/tmp/path/to/export/')
```